# Why does XMLHttpRequest used in ubuntu sdk QML application produce "Object path cannot be empty" error

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qml

When I deploy my application to my Ubuntu phone via ubuntu SDK I get the following error:

```
QNetworkManagerInterface::QNetworkManagerInterface(QObject*) nmReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.345" (uid=32011 pid=29783 comm="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmlscene Main") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="GetDevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=1291 comm="NetworkManager ")"  
"Object path cannot be empty"
```

My `.apparmor` file includes the following:

```js
{
    "policy_groups": [
        "networking",
        "webview",
        "content_exchange",
        "content_exchange_source",
        "connectivity"
    ],
    "policy_version": 1.3
}
```

The security policy for the phone seems correct but creating a Http request fails.

Comment: What's your actual question? I doubt you are truly interested whether anyone else has encountered a similar issue. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: i'm trying to find out why I cannot connect to a Json source using XMLHttpRequest even though I have the correct apparmor permissions

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is a bug. It is filed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/1541686). But do not worry. In normal circumstances, that error should not prevent you from doing XMLhttpRequests. You  should be safe to ignore it.

I too was under the assumption for a while that my requests where failing because of this error, but it turned out (as it often does with XHR) that my handling of xhr.readystate and xhr.status where not correct.